# How to catch SQLException of Data ? (eg. Data not exist)

Tags: java, exception, sqlexception

Searching Solution for this question for long period but still unmanaged to get a answer for this, I'm trying to make a search box in my application made with JAVA.

I want to catch the exception from database and telling user that column doesn't exist or duplication data, may i know how could i do this ?

Comment: because i'm .net developer but required java to finish current assignment, i wish to know how other do for the exception for c# if available =D

Comment: Smt like `try{}catch{/*do what ever you wont*/}`?

Comment: yea...but how i catch message from sql and return back to users ? like content is duplicate, catch exception only will not telling user this message =.=

Comment: Check exception.getMessage().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not really an easy thing to do and the solution will depend a lot on the vendor of the SQL connection (ie, mySQL, oracle, etc)

I have shown one way to do this using pattern matching of the SQLException error message

```
    private final int INEXISTENT_COLUMN_ERROR = ?
    private final int DUPLICATE_DATA_ERROR = ?

    private final String INEXISTENT_COLUMN_PATTERN = ?;
    private final String DUPLICATE_DATA_PATTERN = ?;

    ...

    try {
            ...
        } catch (SQLException e){
            if (e.getErrorCode() == INEXISTENT_COLUMN_ERROR)
               System.out.println("User friendly error message caused by column " + this.matchPattern(e.getMessage(), this.INEXISTENT_COLUMN_PATTERN));
            if (e.getErrorCode() == DUPLICATE_DATA_ERROR)
                System.out.println("User friendly error message caused by duplicate data " + this.matchPattern(e.getMessage(), this.DUPLICATE_DATA_PATTERN));
        }

...

private String matchPattern(final String string, final String pattern) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx for your example and that's what i want, may i know is there a list of DUPLICATE DATA ERROR...or other sql error code ? my primary database is MSSql. Thank you =D

Comment: @spencer you should have a look on google for a list of error codes from your vendor. but you could also figure them out for your self System.out.print(e.getErrorCode())

Comment: Thx =D failed to do in java because using eclipse, weak in debug but work in c# (visual studio) ^^